# Read Word Document and get text for each heading

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a Microsoft word document and I need to extract the text and structure it into a data frame by each section of the document. Each section of the document starts with a Heading. The heading is formatted in Word as "Heading 2". For example:

> **This is section one**
>
> This is the text for the first section.
>
> **This is the second section of the document**
>
> And this is the text for the second section.

I need to get the text for each section in a data frame where in column A I would have the section name and in column B I would have the section text.

I am new to Python and I am trying `docx` package but the only think I was able to do was to get the full text based on a function I found in stackoverflow

**Function (readDocx):**

```
#! python3
from docx import Document

def getText(filename):
    doc = Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

**Code to  get the text:**

```
import readDocx

test = readDocx.getText('THE FILE.docx')
```

I was able to find this loop that identifies the headings. The problem is how to iterate through the document and get each heading and text in a dataframe :

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches


docs = Document("THE FILE.docx")

for paragraph in docs.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name=='Heading 2':
        print (paragraph.text)
```

Comment: it is this one: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ thanks!

Comment: You need to put it in pandas data frame?

Comment: I need it in a table, where column 1 is the section name and column 2 is the section text. A pandas data frame it is OK. Thanks!

Comment: Is the document really that simple? Is there always only one `Normal` paragraph after each `Heading 2`?

Comment: Here you can find an example. I am asking to my colleagues to format the text always like this: Heading > normal text. http://www.emcdda.europa.eu/attachements.cfm/att_248912_EN_Methodological_information_by%20country%202016%20Final.docx Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a `docx` that looks like this

[image]

this could be a starting point:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document("demo.docx")
headings = []
texts = []
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == "Heading 2":
        headings.append(paragraph.text)
    elif paragraph.style.name == "Normal":
        texts.append(paragraph.text)

for h, t in zip(headings, texts):
    print(h, t)
```

Output:

```
Heading, level 2 A plain paragraph having some bold and some italic.
Heading, level 2 Foo
Heading, level 2 Bar
```

I don't know Pandas but it should be easy to get from a list of tuples (produced by `zip`) to a dataframe.

Comment: The format of the document it is always: Heading 2 and normal text.

Comment: That works just fine. The problem starts when I have a section with, for example two paragraphs and other section with three paragraphs. Then I get two values in the headings list and five values in the texts list.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document("demo.docx")
headings = []
texts = []
para = []
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith("Heading"):
        if headings:
            texts.append(para)
        headings.append(paragraph.text)
        para = []
    elif paragraph.style.name == "Normal":
        para.append(paragraph.text)
if para or len(headings)>len(texts):
    texts.append(texts.append(para))

for h, t in zip(headings, texts):
    print(h, t)
```